# Use a type from a different package in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I want to create a package that holds types that I can load somewhere else and use there. But I don't get it to work.

In my case I have something like this:

### types.vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package types is
    constant number : integer := 42;
    subtype fancy_vector is std_logic_vector(10 downto 0);
    type fancy_vector_array is array (4 downto 0) of fancy_vector;
end types;
```

### tb_types.vhdl

```
library ieee;

use work.types.all;

entity tb_types is
end tb_types;

-- If I comment this entity out, everything works as expected
entity dummy is
    port (
        test : in fancy_vector_array
    );
end dummy;

architecture implementation of tb_types is
begin
    main: process begin
        assert (number = 42);
        report "Everything went well";
        wait;
    end process;
end implementation;
```

I analyze and compile the testbench with `ghdl` like this:

```
$ ghdl -i types.vhdl tb_types.vhdl
$ ghdl -m tb_types
tb_types.vhdl:10:26:error: no declaration for "fancy_vector_array"
```

If I comment the dummy entity out, everything works fine as expected. The assertion doesn't trigger and it reports "Everything went well".

What did I do wrong here?

I also tried without `.all` and with `types.fancy_vector_array` and `types.number`. Then it says: `no declaration for "types"`.

Comment: This is about visiblity of use clauses. The first `use work.types.all;` applies to the immediately following entity `tb_types`. If you want it to apply to entity `dummy` too, you need to repeat it after the first entity. Most people put each entity (and its arch) in separate files.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks a lot. I absolutely didn't know about that, it's kind of counter intuitive. Writing the `use work.types.all` twice completely solves it.

Comment: Design units are independently analyzed. There's nothing wrong with putting multiple design entities in the same design file. However a design unit consists of a context clause and a library unit (an entity is a primary unit, and a library unit). A context clause can be empty (context_clause ::= { context_item }) as yours is.

Comment: It's a better solution than having to add syntax to "un_use" the package if the second entity didn't want it...

Comment: I just made two entities so that I can have a testbench for my type declarations. If it compiles, the type declaration works XD

Comment: Also I was goint to make a component of that entity in the architecture.